# how to bubble sort the following code into multi dimensional Array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

This code contain bubble sorting with array. In which I need to use, multidimensional array.

```
public class list {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            int temp;
            int a[] = { 0, 7, 4, 5, 6, 2, -1, 3 };
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
                    if (a[i] < a[j]) {
                        temp = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = temp;
                    }

                }
                System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
            }

        }
    }
}


output:7,6,5,4,3,2,0,-1,
```

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate through a multidimensional array?

Comment: Yes Sir just i have done with an single array. In which I need to do with a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I think this is a basic question, So please give your input and output atleast.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:** If you want to sort 2D array in java then you can check this example.

```
class Sort2D
        {
            public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
            {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                System.out.print("Enter the no. of  rows: "); //inputting number of rows
                int m=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                System.out.print("Enter the no. of columns: "); //inputting number of columns
                int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                int A[][]=new int[m][n]; //creating a 2D array

                /* Inputting the 2D Array */

                for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    {
                        System.out.print("Enter the elements: ");
                        A[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    }
                }        

                /* Printing the original 2D Array */

                System.out.println("The original array:");
                for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(A[i][j]+"\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

                /* Sorting the 2D Array */

                int t=0;
                for(int x=0;x<m;x++)
                {
                    for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                        {
                            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                            {
                                if(A[i][j]>A[x][y])
                                {
                                    t=A[x][y];
                                    A[x][y]=A[i][j];
                                    A[i][j]=t;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                /* Printing the sorted 2D Array */

                System.out.println("The Sorted Array:");
                for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(A[i][j]+"\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to sort one dimension at a time, multiple dimension require multiple runs. So create another method and pass one dimension at a time to the sort method. It also depends on the business case. In any case , bubblesort can't do better than O(n2), infact  it is m*O(n2) for an m*n 2-d  array.

Another strategy might  be , flatten the array from multiple dimensions to a single dimension and then sort the one dimension.